# incomplete build (apk file won't install) after Eclipse update

Tags: android, eclipse, build

My builds were working as expected until I updated Eclipse and Android SDK yesterday.  Now my apk file won't build completely (I can tell because the file size is much smaller) and it won't install on my phone.  Strange thing is, it will still run on the emulator.  I don't get any error messages other than on my phone I install the apk and it says "installed", but when I try to run it, it says "not installed".

All this happened after updating Eclipse.  Initially it wouldn't build at all, but I cleaned the project and now it will build, but not completely.  Any ideas?

Comment: I had issue with library project, that not compiled correctly with ADT 22.. I see 2 solutions, rollback to previous version, or 2nd one I ported my project to gradle and Android Studio until ADT will be fixed

Comment: I can't revert. I tried to revert to ADT 21.0.0 and it was rejected.  Re-installed Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and now I don't have the option to revert since revert history is gone.  Any way to unstall and reinstall ADT?

Comment: Steps to revert to 21.0.1:
1. Download SDK: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r21.0.1-windows.zip (different platform check for format here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. Extract it and run SDK manager
3. Uncheck update to 22, install SDK and platform-tools
4. Download ADT compatible with 21.0.1: https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.0.1.zip
5. Download fresh copy of Eclipse or uninstall ADT from the existing installation
6. Install ADT from archive, follow steps here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html (manually install it)

Comment: I followed your instructions but now Eclipse doesn't recognize java or android import statements.  I couldn't uninstall ADT22 from Eclipse so I install Eclipse Juno for Mobile.  ADT 21.1.0.1 is installed into the new Eclipse but many libraries are missing. Java is still in my path as before, and SDK is there from your instructions.

Comment: I also updated commons-net-2.0.jar to version 3.2 and now the size of the apk file seems normal; however it still won't install on my phone, but will run in the emulator.

Comment: Signing the apk file fixed the problem.  Not sure why it ran on my phone with only debug key before the update.  Maybe the update now requires a release keystore. I also updated the SDK build tools which got overlooked before.  Could not export until I updated the SDK built tools. I am using ADT 22.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. After copy the new android-support-v4.jar. Clean won't worked.

My Apk crashes , there was no LauncherActivity...

After some time I figure out, that the "dexedLibs" in "bin" wasn't generated.

The only thing I do, remove all jars in "libs"  folder via the properties of eclipse and re-add them.

Now all things works with r22 SDK+Eclipse Plugin.

I there another way to "rebuild" dexexlibs?